# C++ Function for struct regardless of template types

Tags: c++, templates

I have a set of functions that work on templated classes, but don't rely on the templated parts of the class.

Templating the function and allowing it to deduce the types would work, but would then compile to multiple functions.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct MyStruct {
    int a;
    T b;
};


bool isLess(MyStruct& lhs, MyStruct& rhs) {
    return lhs.a < rhs.a;
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    MyStruct<int> x {123, 456};
    MyStruct<int> y {789, 123};

    std::cout << isLess(x, y) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: If you define the member function inside the class declaration, you don't need to include any template parameters if they don't change.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Refactor the fields that do not depend on `T` in another class. Make `MyStruct<T>` inherit from it:

```
struct MyStructBase
{
    int a;
};

template<typename T>
struct MyStruct : MyStructBase 
{
    T b;
};

bool isLess(MyStructBase& lhs, MyStructBase& rhs) {
    return lhs.a < rhs.a;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    MyStruct<int> x {123, 456};
    MyStruct<int> y {789, 123};

    std::cout << isLess(x, y) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use inheritance:

```
struct MyStructBase {
    int a;
};

template<typename T>
struct MyStruct : public MyStructBase {
    T b;
};


bool isLess(MyStructBase& lhs, MyStructBase& rhs) {
    return lhs.a < rhs.a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do that:

```
template<typename L, typename R>
auto isLess(L&& lhs, R&& rhs) -> decltype(std::declval<L>().a < std::declval<R>().a) {
    return std::forward<L>(lhs).a < std::forward<R>(rhs).a;
}
```

This will work regardless of the relation between your types, and will not compile to multiple function (see last paragraph). It will allow any types that has a member `a` that is less than comparable.

> Templating the function and allowing it to deduce the types would work, but would then compile to multiple functions.

Bad guess. It's even better than that, it will compile to *no function at all*, since any sane compiler (even msvc) will completely inline the function.

Comment: Very neat and short solution! OP should accept it. _"even msvc"_ LOL :D

Comment: Your return statement is wrong (R instead of L for lhs).

Comment: Oops, sorry, let me fix that.